# How to SNAP before RMAN in deCarta DDS?

Tags: routes, gis, reverse-geocoding, rman

Some of my routes don't work because the deCarta DDS doesn't find any arc near OLL and/or DLL and the server answers:

> RMAN|%S=Cannot find path origin%N=0||

How to make the server search a nearby arc (SNAP) and do the route (RMAN) in a single request?

Comment: As far as I'm aware the only situation where two requests can be done in one is the DDS keyword inside an IMAG query. But for your question I think it'll need to be two separate requests. If you find a way please update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your best bet is to handle it on the client side.

Before you make that call you do not know if you need a SNAP and RMAN, or just an RMAN (I assume).

What you need to do is to run RMAN if there is an error catch it, do a SNAP followed by a new RMAN.

If you do a SNAP and RMAN everytime you will slow down your system with unecessary calls.